# How to remove the error 'Create extension property'Any.second' while accessing the pair values declared in a HashMap in kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, hashmap

I have a Singleton class named ImageStore in which I have declared a Hashmap where value for each is key is a Pair like shown below

```
object ImageStore {

    val imagesNamesMap = hashMapOf(
        R.drawable.africa to Pair("Africa","Afrika"),
        R.drawable.asia to Pair("Asia","Azija"),
        R.drawable.europe to Pair("Europe","Europa"),
        R.drawable.antartica to Pair("Antarctica","Antarktida"),
        R.drawable.airplane to Pair("Aeroplane","Lėktuvas"),
        R.drawable.apple1 to Pair("Apple","Obuolys"),
        R.drawable.key to Pair("Key","raktas"),
        R.drawable.sleep to Pair("to sleep","miegoti)"
    ).toList().shuffled().take(4)).toMap()


}
```

I have a Fragment where I am trying to access the instance of Imagestore and both the values from the Pair , so I have put this code in my Fragment class like show below.

```
 val shuffledImageResources = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap.keys.toList().shuffleList().toMutableList()

        val shuffledImageNames1: List<Pair<String, String>> = shuffledImageResources.mapNotNull { it ->
            val pair = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap[it]
            pair?.let { Pair(pair.first, pair.second) } //
        }
```

Here **first** and **second** from pair.first and pair.second are giving error when I click on **first** from pair.first it give me following message as shown in the image below[image: image for pair.first error message]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9vNP.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo94H.jpg and when i click on the **second** from pair.second , it's giving me this error as shown in below image [image: error message from par.second]

Comment: Is `"miegoti)"` intentional? Didn’t you mean to do `"miegoti”)` and you also have an extra parenthesis after `take(4)`.

Comment: It was by mistake. i have resolved the error, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The inferred type of the value in `imagesNamesMap` is `Any` and not `Pair`. Please try as follows:

```
val imagesNamesMap = hashMapOf(
    R.drawable.africa to Pair("Africa","Afrika"),
    R.drawable.asia to Pair("Asia","Azija"),
    R.drawable.europe to Pair("Europe","Europa"),
    R.drawable.antartica to Pair("Antarctica","Antarktida"),
    R.drawable.airplane to Pair("Aeroplane","Lėktuvas"),
    R.drawable.apple1 to Pair("Apple","Obuolys"),
    R.drawable.key to Pair("Key","raktas"),
    R.drawable.sleep to Pair("to sleep","miegoti")
).toList().shuffled().take(4).toMap()
```

I've removed `)` after `take(4)` and swapped `)` with `"` in `Pair("to sleep","miegoti)"`

Comment: @kolmikaelson Could you please paste you current code for creating `imagesNamesMap`?

Comment: @kolmikaelson the error should be resolved with the snippet I provided because, with that snippet, the correct type is inferred

Comment: Hi, yes, I resolved it with little bit of tweaking the code of Fragment. Thank you so much :)